# PageViewController embedded in containerView shows small margin of previous view

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I've created a viewController with a containerView in which I've embedded a pageViewController. In this pageController I've added 3 viewControllers inside. This seems to work fine, however every time I swipe to the next view it seem to show a little margin on the side of the previous view. What could cause this?

[image]

**ViewDidLoad**

```
    if let firstViewController = orderedViewControllers.first {
        self.pageViewController?.setViewControllers([firstViewController],
            direction: .Forward,
            animated: true,
            completion: nil)
    }
```

**newViewController**

```
func newViewController(view: String) -> UIViewController {
    return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(view)
}
```

**PageControllerDelegate**

```
extension CameraViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
        viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
            guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.indexOf(viewController) else {
                return nil
            }

            let previousIndex = viewControllerIndex - 1

            // User is on the first view controller and swiped left to loop to
            // the last view controller.
            guard previousIndex >= 0 else {
                return orderedViewControllers.last
            }

            guard orderedViewControllers.count > previousIndex else {
                return nil
            }

            return orderedViewControllers[previousIndex]
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
        viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
            guard let viewControllerIndex = orderedViewControllers.indexOf(viewController) else {
                return nil
            }

            let nextIndex = viewControllerIndex + 1
            let orderedViewControllersCount = orderedViewControllers.count

            // User is on the last view controller and swiped right to loop to
            // the first view controller.
            guard orderedViewControllersCount != nextIndex else {
                return orderedViewControllers.first
            }

            guard orderedViewControllersCount > nextIndex else {
                return nil
            }

            return orderedViewControllers[nextIndex]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably speak about **page spacing**. You can edit it in the storyboard. Select your Page View Controller, and open Attributes inspector. There will be corresponding section:

[image]